# How to set width of columns of a DevExpress GridView for MVC dynamically

Tags: gridview, devexpress-mvc

I am using MVC devexpress grid and using customization window feature to add remove columns from grid dynamically. Now I want to keep the width of grid as 100 % of the page always and the columns should be adjusting their width dynamically on adding or removing from grid view.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Width property of your element using `Unit.Percentage()`. For example:

```
column.Width= Unit.Percentage(50);
```